# Trying to simplify code, problems in append

Tags: python, list, append

I have been trying to simplify this code, in previous question I asked a user give me a possible solution but I can't use a list of list, below is the code which I'm trying to simplify:

```
option = int(input("Table to serve "))
while  option != 0:
    menu()
    if option == 1:
        option2 = int(input("Put the code of the food (0 to END): "))
        while option2 != 0:
            menu()
            x = option2 - 1
            table1.append((names[x],prices[x],types[x]))
            option2 = int(input("Put the code of the food (0 to END): "))
```

As you can see it is defined for a single option, but I have 6 options and the code is very long if I copy and paste this 6 times, how could I simplify this in a function taking into account that in:

```
table1.append((names[x],prices[x],types[x]))
```

The name of the table depends on the variable 'option'

Thanks.

EDIT:

```
def files():
    try: 
        file = open("menu.txt","r",1,"utf-8")
    except:
        print("file not found")

    line = file.readline().strip()    
    while line != "":
        parts = line.split(";")
        name = parts[0]
        price = int(parts[1])
        type = parts[2]
        names.append(name)
        prices.append(price)
        types.append(type)

        line = file.readline().strip()

def menu():
    for i in range(len(names)):
        print(i+1," ",names[i], " ", prices[i], " ",types[i]," \n")
```

Comment: What is `menu`? Also what are the espected choices and such?

Comment: can you add the goal of the problem with an example? it is not clear what you need since menu is being called everywhere

Comment: @Jaba I'm going to edit the post with another part of the code

Comment: Thanks for the response but it would be more helpful if you edited your question with the applicible code and explanation.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code although this still doesn't help us understand what it is you're the code is supposed to accomplish. also `files` method is very ambiguous here I see nowhere that it is used

Comment: @Jaba already done, look my code should be able to chose into 6 tables, each table must have a list, in the list the code should save the food elements with all info ( name, price, type) , in the first post I leave the part of the code where I have problems, I need a function to simplify the copy and paste 6 times

Comment: When you find the answer to a question, don't edit it into your question, answer it.

Comment: There is just not enough here to answer this question without making assumptions.

Comment: David, I didn't know / @Jaba If you give me a way to send you the code, I do, I think here the code is too much large, or if you want i can just post as another edit

Comment: Use [hastebin](https://hastebin.com/about.md)

Comment: @Jaba https://pastebin.com/XrgDFqNH